# Check if object is in list (not "by value", but by id)

Tags: python, comparison-operators

Consider the following code:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def __init__(self, a):
...     self.a = a
...   def __eq__(self, other):
...     return self.a==other.a
... 
>>> a=A(1)
>>> b=A(1)
>>> c=A(2)

>>> a==b
True                   # because __eq__ says so
>>> a==c
False                  # because __eq__ says so
>>> a is b
False                  # because they're different objects

>>> l = [b,c]
>>> a in l
True                   # seems to use __eq__ under the hood
```

So, `in` seems to use `__eq__` to determine whether or not something is in a container.

1. Where can one find documentation on this behavior?
2. Is it possible to make `in` use object identity, a.k.a. `a in somelist` if the object `a` is in `somelist`, and not some other object that compares equal to `a`?

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/29692140/674039

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a generator expression:

```
any(o is a for o in l)
```

The behaviour of `in` is documented in the [*Common Sequence Operators* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

> `x in s`
>   `True` if an item of *s* **is equal to** *x*, else `False`

Bold emphasis mine.

If you must use `in`, use a wrapper object with a custom `__eq__` method that uses `is`, or build your own container where a custom [`__contains__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) uses `is` to test against each contained element.

The wrapper could look like this:

```
class IdentityWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, ob):
        self.ob = ob
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other is self.ob
```

Demo:

```
>>> IdentityWrapper(a) in l
False
>>> IdentityWrapper(a) in (l + [a])
True
```

The container could just use the same `any()` function outlined above:

```
class IdentityList(list):
    def __contains__(self, other):
        return any(o is other for o in self)
```

Demo:

```
>>> il = IdentityList(l)
>>> a in il
False
>>> a in IdentityList(l + [a])
True
```

Comment: Doesn't `in` use `__contains__`?

Comment: @DeepSpace: Yes, and if you're writing a sequence, you're supposed to define `__contains__` so that it does what this answer describes.

Comment: I think `in` uses the `__contains__` method of the container, which in turn uses `__eq__`.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to change `A` behaviour, you may prepare thin wrapper for used container. To change how `in` operator behaves, magic method [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) needs to get overridden. Quoting docs:

> Called to implement membership test operators. Should return true if
>   item is in self, false otherwise. For mapping objects, this should
>   consider the keys of the mapping rather than the values or the
>   key-item pairs.

Sample code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a


class IdentityList(list):
    def __contains__(self, obj):
        return any(o is obj for o in self)

a = A(1)
b = A(1)
c = A(2)
container = [b, c]
identity_container = IdentityList(container)
assert a in container  # not desired output (described in question)
assert a not in identity_container  # desired output
```