# Why does np.float('nan') cause problems with dicts, but math.nan does not?

Tags: python, numpy

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300367/why-adding-multiple-nan-in-python-dictionary-giving-multiple-entries) that shows how using nan from numpy causes problems with a dict, why does math.nan behave differently?  (Python3)

```
import math
import numpy as np

d = {math.nan:'baz', math.nan:'bip' }
print(d)
e = {np.float('nan'):'foo', np.float('nan'):'bar' }
print(e)
```

Output

```
{nan: 'bip'}
{nan: 'foo', nan: 'bar'}
```

Comment: Moreover, both below are true:
    `math.nan is math.nan`
    `np.float('nan') is not np.float('nan')`

Comment: And in fact, on many platform, `np.float is float`.

Comment: @wim: On every single platform where `numpy` is an official distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `math.nan` is a module level attribute, so you get the identical object both times. CPython dicts have a shortcut<sup>†</sup> for identity checks

```
>>> any(k == math.nan for k in d)
False
>>> math.nan in d
True
```

With `np.float('nan')` you have a function call, returning different instance each time.  Using Python's built-in `float('nan')` would be similar again, this is not really related to numpy.

```
>>> np.float('nan') is np.float('nan')
False
>>> math.nan is math.nan
True
>>> float('nan') is float('nan')
False
```

<sup>†</sup><sub>Lists, tuples, etc also have this. See [Making an object x such that “x in [x]” returns False](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29692140/674039) for more about that.</sub>